# GestureListener Onfling Function in ANDENGINE

Tags: android, andengine

I have AND ENGINE project and in this project I have 10 slide now I want to go from slide one to slide two in fling mode(from right to left) and vice versa. I tried the Default ON FLING in And Engine Project but its is not calling even I have implement Gesture Listener Interface but its not working. Any suggestion for having ON FLING functionality in AND ENGINE Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add your activity (or view) as a listener of your detector (that means you connect the detector with its listener). And in your **`GestureListener`** you give a reference to your gesture handler (activity or view)

In `MyActivity`:

```
public MyActivity(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    m_Gesture_Detector= new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener(this));
}
public void handleFlingEvent(...)
{
    //do your work here
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    return m_Gesture_Detector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

In gesture listener:

```
public class GestureListener implements 
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener 
{
    MyActivity appliedView; //view who responses to graphical gestures

    public GestureListener(MyActivity gestureHandler) 
    {
        this.appliedView = gestureHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) 
    {
        appliedView.handleFlingEvent(...);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I use it in ANDENGINE project because it contains functions like onCreateScene , onCreateResources and CreateEngineOptions

Comment: for `AndEngine`, using gesture handling cannot be applied to game entities. You must you **MouseJoint** to move your physics objects and use `IOnSceneTouchListener`, `IOnAreaTouchListener` to handle touch events. You should see MouseJoint sample in AndEngine source code samples.

Comment: in AndEngine, you CAN apply `Fling` motion event for activity with IAeaShape (Sprite) by modify its motion with fling velocity param.  But this way of implementation is not so nice, should use AndEngine touch handlers as common game practice